Why are they integrating from infinity to $r$ in the derivation of GPE formula?
We know that $$F_G = \frac{G M m}{r^2}.$$
Now according to the definition of work done they are giving the derivation formula $$W_G = \int_{\infty}^{r} \frac{G M m}{r^2} \, dr.$$
but infinity as the lower limit seems wrong, because infinity should be at top as it is the higher limit.
Using this law for the numerical values of integrals : $$\int_{a}^{b} f(\alpha) \, d\alpha \neq \int_{b}^{a} f(\alpha) \, d\alpha.$$
This law is true as the first integral evaluated will be $F(b)-F(a)$ but for the second one it will be $F(a)-F(b)$ which is the first one.
So it is wrong to interchange the limits of the integration. Then why can we put the infinity at the lower end even if it is higher than $r$?
Btw I am a 9th grader and all of this integration and stuff is self-learnt.

Welcome to Physics.SE. As a general comment, when referring to external resources you should specify what they are. e.g. in this case, who exactly are "they".

What is the value of the integrand at $r=\infty$?

Not a dumb question at all. A general property of integrals is that when switching the integral bounds, there is just an overall minus sign:
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = - \int_b^af(x)dx.$$
So, why do we even bother writing the integral with the upper bound $a$ lower than the lower bound $\infty$? In this case, there is a physical motivation: work is the amount of energy required to bring from a radius $+\infty$ to a radius $r$ the object of mass $m$ to the other object. So, even if both mathematical formulations (with the minus sign) are equivalent, the author likely wants you to see this work happening as a process where one object is coming next to the other.

There is no rule that the upper limit should be larger than the lower limit of the integal. For the case of work, the choice of limits simply tells you for what motion is the work calculated. The lower limit is the initial position and the upper limit the final position. So, the $$\int_A^B \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} $$ is the work done by the force F on a body whne the body moves from A to B. The integral $$\int_B^A \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} $$ is the work done by the same force when the body moves from B to A. Both choices of limits are valid and which one you need depends on the context. So, the work done by the gravitational force when the mass m is brought from infinit distance (just far-far away) to the distance r from the mass M will be given by the integral from $\infty$ to r.This work is positive, the force acts in the direction of motion (attraction force). The work done by gravity when the body is moved from r to $\infty$ is given by the integral from r to $\infty$ and this will be negative (the force opposes the motion). When calculating work you always need to know what is the force and what is the motion during which the work is calculated.

We have to find out the amount of work done by the force on the mass on bringing it from "infinity to r" does it start to resonate as to why we take the lower limit $\infty$? think of drawing a vector of its path, now you got to integrate it from the tail of that vector to the head of it.

A couple of simple fixes. One is, make vectors vectors, even in 1D. We can do that with proper signage:
$$ F = -\frac{GMm}{r} $$
as gravity acts to shrink $r$.
Then we define $R_0$ to be where $\Phi(R_0) \equiv 0$, and integrate $dW$ from $R_0$ to a rando coordinate where we measure $\Phi(r)$:
$$ \Phi(r) = \int_{r'=R_0}^{r'=r} F(r')dr' $$
(Note also: the integrand variable is a so called dummy variable--though here, it represents the path taken from $R_0$ to $r$, so I don't like calling it a dummy. Eitherway: you can't call it $r$).
Then, choose $R_0=\infty$, and expand the signed $F$:
$$ \Phi(r) = \int_{r'=\infty}^{r'=r} -\frac{GMm}{r'^2}dr' $$
$$ \Phi(r) = -\frac{GMm} {r'}\Big|^{r'=r}_{r'=\infty} = -\frac{GMm} r $$

By definition, zero gravitational force occurs at infinity and maximum gravitational force occurs at "r".  Total work done is the integral of a force through a distance.  Since the integral is done in terms of distance, this means that the infinity limit at the bottom of the integral is, in a sense, hiding the fact that the integral starts at zero gravitational force.

I think that part of your uncertainty comes from your equation $F_{\rm G} = \frac{G M m}{r^2}.$
This equation gives you the magnitude of the gravitational force but there is no information about its direction.
Work done is the product of a force and a displacement along the line of action of the force.
If both force and displacement are in the same direction the work done is positive whereas if the force and displacement are in opposite directions the work done is negative.
Your integral for $W_{\rm G}$ starts at the lower limit, $\infty$, and finishes at the upper limit, $r$ and thus the displacement is in the same direction as the gravitational force resulting in the work done being positive as might be expected as the gravitational force is doing positive work.
If you had switched the limits of integration that would have represented a displacement in the opposite direction to the gravitational force direction and result in negative work being done by the gravitational force which is not correct.
Using vector notation $\vec F_{\rm G} = \frac{G M m}{r^2}(-\hat r)$ where $\vec r$ is the unit vector pointing away from the origin, ie the gravitational force is towards the origin.
Assume that one starts at displacement $r\,\hat r$ and move to a displacement $(r+dr)\,\hat r$ then the force $\vec F_{\rm G}$ has been displaced $\underbrace{(r+dr)\,\hat r}_{\rm final} - \underbrace{r\,\hat r}_{\rm initial} = dr\,\hat r$.
Thus the work done by the gravitational force in being displaced by $dr\,\hat r$ is $-\frac{G M m}{r^2}\,\hat r\cdot dr\,\hat r = -\frac{G M m}{r^2}\,dr$ because $\hat r \cdot \hat r =1$.

If $dr$ is positive, lower limit of integration $r$ and upper limit
of integration $\infty$, then the gravitational force does negative
work, ie $\displaystyle \int^\infty_r -\frac{G M m}{r^2}\,dr = -\frac{G M m}{r^2} $.
If $dr$ is negative, lower limit of integration $\infty$ and upper
limit of integration $r$, then the gravitational force does positive
work, ie $\displaystyle \int_\infty^r -\frac{G M m}{r^2}\,dr = +\frac{G M m}{r^2} $.

The limits of integration set the direction of travel, $W_{\rm G} = \displaystyle \int_{\rm start}^{\rm finish}-\frac{G M m}{r^2}\,dr$, the Mathematics does the work for you.
